# Error after I create new GitHub access token

Tags: github, access-token

I followed the steps of creating a new token, and then I replace it on my Mac keychain.
After that, I tried to push my code into GitHub, but then got the same error:

```
Remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
Remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
```

Why this error is happening if I created a new token ? What I am missing in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Creating the personal token change the origin like this :

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:<MYTOKEN>@github.com/username/repo.git
```